# Node and NPM path in OSX

Tags: node.js, macos

I have a very strange configuration issue.

When logging to machine (SSH session) and executing the following commands using interactive shell, they succeed:

```
node --version
npm --v
```

However, when I execute the following through script from remote machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script input arguments
user=${1} 
server=${2} 

#Tell the shell to quote your variables to be eval-safe!
printf -v user_q '%q' "$user"
printf -v server_q '%q' "$server"
#

# Script variables
address="$user_q"@"$server_q"
#

function run {
    ssh "$address" /bin/bash "$@"
}


run << SSHCONNECTION

node --version
npm --v

 exit
SSHCONNECTION
```

I get the following output:

> /bin/bash: line 2: node: command not found
>
> /bin/bash: line 3: npm: command not found

I am conscious that the issue may be the in .bash_profile file configuration

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Also, here is result of `npm config get prefix`:

> /usr/local

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you run `which npm` and `which node` on the machine?

Comment: @rakeshdas `/usr/local/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/npm`

Comment: In your script, what if you just used the directory you got back to run the command: `/usr/local/bin/node --version` ?

Comment: I get the output using `/usr/local/bin/node --version` , but don't get the output for `/usr/local/bin/npm --v` : env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: Try running this on the remote machine: `sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: @rakeshdas /usr/local/bin/node already exists on the box, and `which node` resolves to it. Ran the command to create the link and got the following output: `ln: /usr/local/bin/node: File exists`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what happened is due to the fact `.bash_profile` is only executed when bash is invoked for an interactive shell, more info about this here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files

When invoking and passing the script directly to /bin/bash, it will behave as a non-interactive shell which the default behaviour to not read the `.bash_profile`.

I would suggest setting you PATH variable in `/etc/environment` so it will take affect for all users and all manners of scripting.