# npm: command not found in jenkins for MAC OS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, jenkins

I tried to implement CI/CD pipeline by first cloning a react project from git and then build the project in my local machine.

I have reinstalled node, configured nodejs in jenkins and tried adding PATH but nothing worked for me..

> Method one that i tried: I create a freestyle item and added below script after providing the git repo link under pipeline script from SCM.. this is throwing me npm command not found error.

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew
npm install
```

**Edit:**

`I restarted jenkins and lost my old build..now, after restarting jenkins and running the build(above method 1 steps) i see groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: install for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

> Second method i tried is by creating a new pipeline item and passing pipeline script as below.

```
pipeline{
agent any

tools {nodejs "default"}
stages{
    stage('Build'){
        steps{
            git 'git@github.com:patebija/simple-node-js-react-npm-app.git'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Edit:**

`After restarting jenkins, when i run the above steps(method 2), i still see "npm: command not found"(Not sure if **sh 'npm install'** is valid in MACOS.. And if i just give **npm install** removing sh, i get exception -- groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: install for class: groovy.lang.Binding`  .

I am new to jenkins and stuck with this for a long time...Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export PATH=/opt/homebrew` would override all the paths stored in $PATH, to replace it with that unique one.
That would not work very well, since all system commands would no longer be referenced.

Usually, you would [add the npm path to the existing PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43482525/6309)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/npm:/usr/local/bin/node:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

(Plus possibly your [existing npm packages path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72862173/6309))

Make sure your Jenkins main controller and agents are running with your account (not as root), in order for them to inherit your environment variables.
So check first `npm` or `git` are working properly from your shell session, *then* launch Jenkins, and try executing pipelines.

Comment: When i try using pipeline script with


stage('Build'){
        steps{
            git 'git@github.com:patebija/simple-node-js-react-npm-app.git'
            npm install
        }


I am getting below exception..


groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: install for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: @StackD Those are completely different questions. After a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException%3A+No+such+property%3A+install+for+class%3A+groovy.lang.Binding&oq=groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException%3A+No+such+property%3A+install+for+class%3A+groovy.lang.Binding&aqs=chrome..69i57.210j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), see if https://stackoverflow.com/q/57410799/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/47064135/6309 could help.